# Raw SQL query or Doctrine_Query? What is the best in performance?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-query

I made this query in raw SQL and need some help moving to Doctrine:

```
SELECT 
    re . *, t.tipo, m.patente, o.nombre, de.revisado
FROM
    sdriving_registros_emisores re
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_turno t ON re.idturno = t.idturno
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_maquina_emisor me ON me.idmaquinaemisor = re.maquinaemisorid
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_maquina m ON me.idmaquina = m.idmaquina
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_operador o ON re.idoperador = o.idoperador
        LEFT JOIN
    sdriving_detalle_emisores de ON de.idregistros = re.idregistros
WHERE
    o.idempresa = 1
```

Also I wish to know what's the best method in perfomance: executing raw query or using Doctrine Query or something else

Comment: doctrine itself is too heavy-weight. there are other light-weight DB libraries in the Internet

Comment: @ShivanRaptor but the main problem is that I'm using Symfony :-(